# Laravel sporadic EncryptException "Could not encrypt the data." in EncryptCookies

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We have a CentOS LAMP server with PHP5.6.37, openSSL 1.0.2, Laravel 5.4.

Sporadically we receive the following error:

```
exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\EncryptException' with message 'Could not encrypt the data.' in ./Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:95
Stack trace:
 #0 ./Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(131): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->encrypt('KoKVTECWZF4A8x7...')
 #1 ./Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->encrypt(Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
```

The problematic code is:

```
$json = json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac'));
if (!is_string($json)) {
    throw new EncryptException('Could not encrypt the data.');
}
```

These exceptions happen sporadically, all in the early morning hours (3AM-8AM) , sometimes there are no errors for couple of weeks, then they happen every consecutive day.

ATM we cannot switch to PHP7.

**EDIT 1:**

I have logged the values, where the program crashes during the night. If I rerun the code, I get normal response without an Exception.

````
$value = 'a51446732955fcf3bb467fc135741ae7956dc247d562b16157de231b8d792400';
$mac = 'Xdo0mGNCeX4p2AHj4cgbmounu3F2bql05uSmve7DDmUWpmMJ1ysmsSrGPg+57N52FxqszqDU5PBTGMihan7ZZQ==';
echo json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac'));

1{"iv":"yHUQHrhaXq7T+VikdvXuqQ==","value":"a51446732955fcf3bb467fc135741ae7956dc247d562b16157de231b8d792400","mac":"Xdo0mGNCeX4p2AHj4cgbmounu3F2bql05uSmve7DDmUWpmMJ1ysmsSrGPg+57N52FxqszqDU5PBTGMihan7ZZQ=="}```
````

Comment: Looks kind of uncritical. Maybe you should trace the 3 values for the error case (if `value` is the ciphertext, this should be possible without security risk).

Comment: Log the values in the failure case, maybe you'll figure something out.